# using fscanf(file, %x, x) and converting hex to ints in C

Tags: c, hex, scanf

I want to use fscanf to *check* if something is a hex number.
For example, I want to call

```
if(fscanf(file,"%x", &u))
```

just like one could call this with strings and ints. The problem is this:
First, what type should u be?
Second, once I get this hex, ie if the if statement passes, how could I convert u to an integer?

NOTE:
I want

```
if(fscanf(file, "%x", &u) == 1)
```

to be true iff the number read in is 0x_*_* and false otherwise.
I have tried

```
if(fscanf(file, "0x%x", &u) == 1)
```

but that is returning false for for hex numbers

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf - see the table.

Comment: Did you know that whatever you call it, be it `char`, `int`, `float`, or whatever, at the end of the day, to a computer, it's just binary?

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need to convert this number to type int so I can test the int later

Answer (score 2):

From the `scanf` man page:

> x, X  Matches an optionally signed hexadecimal integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to *unsigned int*.

You don't need to do anything to convert it to an integer, that's what `scanf` does for you.

If you specifically want to match `0x___`, put that into the format string:

```
if (fscanf(file, "0x%x", &u) == 1)
```

Full code that I have tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int u;
    if (scanf("0x%x", &u) == 1) {
        printf("Read hex: %u\n", u);
    } else if (scanf("%u", &u) == 1) {
        printf("Read decimal: %u\n", u);
    }
}
```

Comment: so the "u" should be an unsigned int? and if(fscanf(file,"%x", &u)) will *only* return true if it reads something of 0x___ format?

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: no, it doesn't require the `0x` prefix. It will read anything that looks like a hexadecimal number.

Comment: so this is a problem because it will return true for integers as well

Comment: If you want to match `0x`, you can explicitly add that: `"0x%x"`, or if you want one of `0x` or `0X`, then you can use `"0%*[xX]%x"`.  The return value from `fscanf()` will be 1 (which is true, but so is -1 which is the usual value for EOF) when the match works. Get into the habit of testing for the expected number of matched values — it is safest in the long run.

Comment: yup. I was thinking I could fscanf (%d) before fscanf(%x), that would allow the hex numbers to filter through as well. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use `%i`. It will treat the number as hex if it starts with `0x`, octal if it starts with `0`, and decimal otherwise.

Comment: Note - `fscanf()` returns the _number of arguments matched_ , which is why the `==1` test is the right one. @AlexKornhauser was testing for `true` - "any nonzero value". That is risky (at end of file, `fscanf` will return EOF which is -1 if I am not mistaken: "true", but "wrong").

Comment: With `"%x"`, the scanned string may _optionally_ match `0x` or `0X`.  C11dr §7.22.1.4 3.

Comment: I'm trying to use if(fscanf(file, "0x%x, &u) and then else if(fscanf(file, %d, &d) and the fscanf just reads it as this: it reads in the int 0, and then the x____ it reads as a string which i test later...

Comment: @chux But he wants it to **require** `0x`.

Comment: exactly, if it doesn't require 0x, it will read in an int. I will update the question

Comment: @Barmar I see in a later comment OP's interest as you suggest. Note: a format of `"0x%x"` will match "0x0x123".

Comment: @Barmar The updated solution fails for "0".  The first `scanf()` consumes the `0` and the second `scanf()` does not see it.  Maybe doing the decimal `scanf()` first?  Nah I expect that has trouble too.

Comment: solution not working for me either. How bout this:
fscanf(file, "0x%s", s) then convert that String to an int?

Comment: Why not use `%i` like I suggested earlier?

Comment: @chux decimal scanf consumes 0

Comment: @Alex Kornhauser Yes this is a puzzle.  I think a `"%[xX0-9A-Fa-f]"` into a buffer for post processing may do the trick.

Comment: It sounds like you need to write a parser, not just use `scanf`.

Comment: Perhaps, but its this single case that is catching me. I converted the hex to a string by using "0x%s", off topic but any idea how to get that string of hex chars to an int?

Comment: use `strtod` and include the `0x` prefix, it will convert the hex to int.

Comment: `strtol()` rather than `strtod()`.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion on @Barmar deserves the credit.

Read the data in and process it a number of ways  via `sscanf()` or `strtol()`.

```
unsigned u;
char buf[27];
if (scanf("%26[xX0-9A-Fa-f]", buf) != 1)
  ;//handle_bad_input();
else {
  char ch;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%u%c", &u, &ch) == 1)
    printf("decimal found %u", u);
  else if (sscanf(buf, "0x%X", &u) == 1)
    printf("hexadecimal found 0x%X", u);
  else
    ;//handle_bad_input();
  }
```

Comment: thinking of doing an fgetc to check for '0' then 'x' :/

Comment: @Alex Kornhauser I rather suggest a higher level view and use `fgets()` to get the whole line and then process it as a decimal or hex string.  But that affects the larger context.  In general, avoid `scanf()`, when it fails to parse as expected, you are SOL.  I just don't know the higher level concerns that drive this issue that would point one way or the other.

Comment: alright, I'm using a combo of fgets and fscanf. I turned 0x___ into a string detailing they are hex values, ie, 0x005 is now HEX 005. Any idea how i can then convert 005 to an int? You mentioned strtol but I don't see any good documentation on it. I know its off topic but can I see an example?

Comment: @Alex Kornhauser I hope you mean `fgets()/sscanf()` and not `fgets()/fscanf()`.

Comment: @Alex Kornhauser I do not see a robust simple solution with `strtol()` and the "0x" prefix requirement.  Try your `fgetc()` and test on `0`.

Comment: got it, its params are a (string, optional endpoint, base of int taking in)